# Character in Encrypted String (PHP/MySQLI) Causing String to Terminate - Cant't Figure Out How To Escape it

Tags: php, string, mysqli, escaping

So I am pulling some info from a database using PHP/MySQLI, strictly a row that contains encrypted text, thus some odd characters. Here is an example of an encrypted string I am pulling from the database:

`5Ø·§—X*–Á»ºNKoÜÌ‹.P÷\úfô<96«Ñf÷çÌ› ¤Í·Ömm}u7^YH""²¤"8ªMFëÄ·zEQºªòÔvþŸÜ_¼#ú—PLRUÜ.à¤'WÏ‰&šÖ]pÇÑ©»\rz±DÐ÷£x6w`

When I run my simple decrypt function, it cuts off before the entire string has been decrypted. Even if I just attempt to echo out the above string, one of the `'` or `"` characters from the encrypted string causes it to escape. I tried mysqli_real_escape, and that made the decrypt function terminate earlier. I can post my encrypt/decrypt if necessary, but I know that isn't the problem. I just can't figure out how to let a string of characters such as ' and " display correctly and terminate my output.

I hope this all makes sense, I tried describing the best I could. Next step is live examples, but I'm hoping my issue is fairly common and someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks much!

Comment: Have you tried HTML source in your browser?

Comment: @YourCommonSense What?

Answer (score -1):

just a guess, since you don't offer too much information:
try to convert your encoding with mysql and make sure it's the same encoding you use on your html-page:

```
SELECT CONVERT(encrypted_text USING utf8) AS encrypted_text_utf8 FROM table WHERE 1
```